# short of help VERSUS short on help

Tags: meaning

> The place was short of help.
>
> The place was short on help.

Do you think that 1 means that the place needs more help to get and 2 means the place doesn't provide enough help to someone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both constructions may have either meaning and both would be understood in context by many English speakers.